# Select all checkboxes not working, jsfiddle included

Tags: jquery

Ive searched may threads on here on this, and no solutions have worked for me, does anyone know whats up with this fiddle?
http://jsfiddle.net/9dLGD/
Thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(function () {
         $('#SelectAll').click(function () {
             $('#Suppliers').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
         });
     });
 });
<input name="SelectAll" type="checkbox">Select All
<input name="Suppliers" type="checkbox" value="1">Bob
<input name="Suppliers" type="checkbox" value="2">Bill
<input name="Suppliers" type="checkbox" value="3">Sandy
<input name="Suppliers" type="checkbox" value="4">Sue
<input name="Suppliers" type="checkbox" value="5">Fred
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like you want this:

```
$('input[name=SelectAll]').click(function () {
    $('input[name=Suppliers]').prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```

There is no `id` with name `SelectAll` or `Suppliers` in your HTML. Either add those ids to that two checkboxes or use above code which select `input` elements by their names.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dLGD/2/)**

Comment: Why would he 'add those id's to his checkboxes'? an ID should be unique.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul maybe you don't understand what I means. I suggest him to add two `ids`: `SelectAll` and `Suppliers` to the first two checkboxes

Comment: What use is that for a Select All option? an ID would only allow him to select one... in which case he might as well just make it another checkbox as he has.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

-You have two DOM ready functions

-You dont have anything with an ID of `Suppliers`, you have a `name`!

-Use `.prop()` to change attributes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name=SelectAll").change(function() {
        $(":checkbox[name=Suppliers]").prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9dLGD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {             
         $('#SelectAll').click(function () {
             $('input[name=Suppliers]:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
         });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Felix answer but I always use the case of de-checking a check box to uncheck them all like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[name="SelectAll"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) $('input[name="Suppliers"]').prop('checked', true);
    else $('input[name="Suppliers"]').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```